# TypeToken.getParameterized in Jackson json

Tags: java, android, jackson, gson, moshi

In GSON I can next:

```
Type envelopeType = TypeToken.getParameterized(RestResponse.class, type).getType();
```

In Moshi:

```
Type envelopeType = Types.newParameterizedType(RestResponse.class, type);
```

How can I do it with Jackson json?

Answer (score 1):

[TypeFactory](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html), which is part of jackson-databind, might provide the methods you are looking for.